# Appending Child Models to a Parent Model in Ember.js

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

I have a parent model that has many child models, for example:

```
App.Blog = Ember.Object.extend({})
App.Comment = Ember.Object.extend({})
```

Then I have a view for the Blog:

```
window.App.BlogView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: 'app_templates_blog'
```

Now, when I initially retrieve a Blog via my REST API, it contains the first 10 Comments or so. Those are instantiated like this:

```
window.App.Blog.reopenClass
  create: (obj) ->
    Object.tap @_super(obj), (result) =>
      if result.comments
        result.comments = result.comments.map (p) => App.Comment.create(p)
```

I display by blog by calling BlogView.set('blog', blogInstance) and everything is displaying perfectly.

However!

I am implementing an infinite scroll, so when the end user gets to the bottom of the comments, I want to load more. I do this via REST, but I can't for the life of me get them to display by appending them.

This is what my morePosts() method looks like in BlogView:

```
moreComments: () ->
  blog = @get('blog')

  jQuery.getJSON "/blogs/#{blog.get('id')}/comments", (result) =>        
    comments = blog.get('comments')
    result.each (c) => comments.push(App.Comment.create(c))
    blog.set('comments', comments)
    this.set('blog', blog)
```

However, this never seems to add the new comments. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly support Ember's bindings and observers, you need to use KVO aware getters and setters. Just as you use `get` and `set` for standard properties, you also have to use special methods for Arrays. In this case, you'd use `pushObject`. You can see a full list of the functions implemented here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/mutable_array.js.